# Is there a possibility to get data from google analitycs to CRM via API or else?

Tags: google-api, integration, crm, bitrix

We have an web site and CRM. User fills form on a web page then we send this data into CRM as contact. Also Google analitycs gets more info about this user directly from web site. Is there any possible way to get data from Analitycs to combine it with CRM data?

If this is important: Bitrix24.com is used as CRM (installed on our server).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use google analitycs api?

Comment: Can't find export description. Only how to import data to analitics.

Comment: I need not reports. I need data by users. Like: User1/from:google.com/searchphrase:something/pagesviewed:2/etc..User2/from:yahoo.com/searchphrase:nothing/pagesviewed:5/etc..

Comment: Maybe I need make my self clear. For example: I have a web site that sends data to GA and store user-id or client-id in our CRM. Can I devide data that I've got from GA by each user? In some way using client-id to get Source, Campaign, Count of Sessions of specific user, Count of Pageviews, Medium, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need this web-site: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.mcf.get to construct API-request.

Set your `CustomerID` in `filters` field like this: `mcf:adwordsCustomerIDPath=={customerID1}`

Comment: Thank you. I will try it as soon as possible)